# Emacs input-decode-map for terminal

Tags: emacs, terminal-emulator

I have asked a question about Ctrl-arrow keybinding in Emacs in terminal:

[Emacs Ctrl modifiers don't work in console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13131367/emacs-ctrl-modifiers-dont-work-in-console)

And was told, that Linux terminal emulator doesn't process this combination. I managed to create a file for `loadkeys` command, that processes these keys:

```
control keycode 105 = F100
string F100 = "\033[[left"
control keycode 106 = F101
string F101 = "\033[[right"
```

Then loaded it from root:

```
#loadkeys ./funcskeys
```

After that every time I click Ctrl-right or Ctrl-left in console, I get 'right' or 'left' printed. Now I need to process this in Emacs. As far as I understand from this question:

[Binding M-<up> / M-<down> in Emacs 23.1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351044/binding-m-up-m-down-in-emacs-23-1-1)

it must be done, using `input-decode-map` function. But I couldn't make it work. Plz, help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your "funcskeys" file slightly to produce the following escape sequences:

```
control keycode 105 = F100
string F100 = "\033[1;5D"
control keycode 106 = F101
string F101 = "\033[1;5C"
```

Then add the following lines to your `.emacs` file:

```
(define-key input-decode-map "\e[1;5C" [(control right)])
(define-key input-decode-map "\e[1;5D" [(control left)])
```

After running `loadkeys` and restarting Emacs, <kbd>CTRL+left</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL+right</kbd> should work. You can verify this by typing:

<kbd>C-h k C-right</kbd>

and

<kbd>C-h k C-left</kbd>

To actually bind these keystrokes to a command, such as `forward-word`, you might have to add the following lines to your `.emacs` file as well:

```
(global-set-key [(control right)] 'forward-word)
(global-set-key [(control left)] 'backward-word)
```

Note that this whole approach specifically only makes the key combinations <kbd>CTRL+left</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL+right</kbd> work. It *does not* for instance make <kbd>ALT+left</kbd> / <kbd>ALT+right</kbd> work, or any other key combinations involving the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> character.

Comment: I am not sure why, but your approach didn't work. I made it with (global-set-key "\M-[1;5C" 'forward-word). Then your elisp code is not necessary. Do you know, what's wrong?

Comment: Sorry, but "didn't work" alone is not enough information to have an idea what's wrong. But try the variation I just made.

Comment: Great! Regarding the other keys: if you have access to some other terminal emulation, like e.g., gnome-terminal, it would make sense to use the same key escape sequences. See my answer to your previous question to find out how to get these sequences.

Comment: I added a detailed algorithm to the previous question for the people, who will face the same problem.